# Unterschied zwischen "knackig" und "knusprig"

Tags: vocabulary

Wo liegt eigentlich der Unterschied zwischen *knackig* und *knusprig*?

Manchen Wörterbücher nach, sind sie synonyme; Ich habe auch gefunden, dass *knusprig* ein Unterbegriff von *knackig* ist.

Comment: Knusprig können nur Substanzen sein, die Krümel ergeben. Ein Schokoladenriegel kann *knackig* sein, aber nicht *knusprig* (außer, er enthält Keksstücke).

Comment: Knuspriges Knuspermüsli und knackige Knackwurst :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add your own research effort, and why a dictionary did not help you.

Comment: @KilianFoth Wenn ich rohe Nudeln esse, sind sie für meinen Begriff eher knusprig als knackig – nachdem ich sie einmal knackend grob zerkleinert hab –, obwohl sie keine Krümel ergeben …

Comment: @KilianFoth: Oder Krokant.

Comment: Knusprig kann auch eine Schweinshaxe sein. Mädchen-Pos nicht. Die sind eher knackig.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ich konzentriere mich auf *knackig* und *knusprig* im Bezug auf Essen.

Im Duden steht:

> knusprig = frisch gebacken oder gebraten und mit harter, leicht platzender Kruste [1](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/knusprig)

Beispiele:

- knuspriges Brot/Brötchen/Gebäck
- eine knusprig gebratene Gans
- knusprige Chips/Bratkartoffeln

(ein Synomyme wäre auch "kross")

> knackig = beim Hineinbeißen oder Eindrücken einen kurzen, harten, hellen Ton hervorbringend [2](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/knackig)

Beispiele:

- knackiges Gemüse
- ein knackiger Apfel
- eine knackige Wurst

Answer (score 5):

Ich stimme dieser Antwort von Kilian Forth zu:

> Knusprig können nur Substanzen sein, die Krümel ergeben. Ein Schokoladenriegel kann knackig sein, aber nicht knusprig (außer, er enthält Keksstücke).

Als Ergänzung zur Verwendung sei noch gesagt, dass beide Wörter zwar in der Regel in einem kulinarischen Kontext genutzt werden, knusprig würde *ich* jedoch *ausschließlich* für die Beschreibung von Essen nutzen (“Der Keks ist knusprig”). Knackig kann jedoch unter Umständen in anderen Kontexten genutzt werden. So wird speziell in der Umgangssprache (ich spreche nur für manche, geographischen Regionen wie beispielsweise Bayern) knackig auch für die Beschreibung der Attraktivität einer Person sowie derer Körperpartien genutzt (“der Mann dort hat aber einen knackigen Po!”), oder auch für die hohe Schwierigkeit einer Handlung (“Diese Kletterroute war ganz schön knackig!”). Dies sind aber, wie erwähnt, sehr umgangssprachliche und/oder rustikale Terme und sollten nur in diesem Kontext benutzt werden, wenn man sich sicher ist, dass man sie richtig benutzt, da speziell bei der Beschreibung von Körperpartien schnell Missverständnisse und Fehlinterpretationen auftreten können.

Comment: Duden listet für [knusprig](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/knusprig) eine sehr ähnliche umgangsprachliche Bedeutung.

Comment: Das ist korrekt, das war missverständlich. Es gibt geographische Regionen, in denen auch knusprig für die Wohlgeformtheit von Körperpartien oder Personen genutzt wird, leider habe ich hierfür jedoch kein genaueres Wissen und kann nur (begrenzt) für die Nutzung von "knackig" im nicht-kulinarischen Sinne in manchen Gegenden Bayerns bürgen. Es ist also weiterhin davon abzuraten die Wörter außerhalb der von Kilian Forth definierten Bedeutung zu benutzen. Ich habe meinen Post entsprechende editiert.

Comment: @Em1 Regionalismus? Ich würde ausschließlich "knackig", nicht "knusprig" verwenden. Sagt der Atlas was? (Edit: nein.)

Comment: Hier hat jemand noch nie eine knisprig gebratene Schweinshaxe gegessen. Die gibt aber keine Krümel.

Comment: Schweinshaxe, genauso wie Schweinsbraten usw. habe ich alles schon gegessen. Und natürlich gibt es keine BROTkrümel, aber dennoch bröselt die Haxe. Das ist doch imho die genaue definition von knusprig im Gegensatz zu knackig. Ein Apfel oder Salat sind doch gerade knackig, weil sie nicht bröseln und noch dazu einen etwas weniger trockenen Ton abgeben (der aber schwerer objektiv in einem Lexikon zu spezifizieren ist). Die Logik ist bisschen zirkulär, aber:

tl;dr: Eine knusprige Kruste bröselt imho definitiv.

Answer (score 2):

Das lässt sich auf den Unterschied zwischen *knacken* und *knuspern* zurückführen. Obwohl hier zurecht oft die Essensanalogie bemüht wird, arbeite ich den Unterschied mal anhand eines Fußbodens heraus:

- Wenn es beim Laufen über den Boden *knackt,* dann ist das ein kurzes, einmaliges Geräusch, das zum Beispiel auf einen brechenden Balken hindeutet.
- Wenn es beim Laufen über den Boden *knuspert,* dann ist das Geräusch regelmäßig wiederkehrend und ein Indiz dafür, dass dringend zusammengekehrt oder Staub gesaugt werden sollte.

Das lässt sich auch aufs Essen übertragen. *Knackig* geht eher in Richtung einmaliges Knacken oder distinkt voneinander verschiedene Knackvorgänge, während *knusprig* eher in Richtung gleichmäßiges Hintergrundknuspern geht. Knacken würde das Essen bei einem Kauvorgang idealerweise nur einmal – dann, wenn es den Zähnen nachgibt und bricht. Knuspern kann es den ganzen Kauweg hindurch.

Comment: Dass es beim Laufen über den Boden knuspert, das will ich mal sehen! Bzw. hören. Und bei mir müsste wahrlich dringend mal gesaugt werden, aber hier knuspert nix. YouTube! Und wenn es beim Laufen knackt: Hoffen, es ist ein Balken und nicht das Fußgelenk. :)